# How to Display Video Stream in GTk using V4l2?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk3, v4l2

I'm using V4l2 APIs to access webcam, I'm able to access the webcam and store data in buffer,

How to put this buffer in Display using gtk.

Version I'm using is GTK3.0 .
These are my streaming properties.

```
struct v4l2_format format;
format.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE;
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
format.fmt.pix.width = 800;
format.fmt.pix.height = 600;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.